# JSF User Authentication with Spring LDAP from different projects

Tags: spring, jsf, authentication

My Authenticate menthod (authenticate(username, password)) is method is in Spring LDAp project. and i tested it is working fine.(here my project name is Spring-Ldap-authentication )

My user log in process will be done from JSF web project. Here i have my front-end and bean calss. I want to access the authenticate(username, password) from spring-Ldap-authenticate. How we are able to do this one.

Answer (score 0):

Put your authentication project in an JAR and add this JAR to your Web Project.